# Error while using the Delta Lake source in Spark 2.4 (Hdinsight)

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, delta-lake

Getting below error , same code is working in Databricks but not in Hdinsight. I have added the delta library  and hadoop-azure library also in the classpath.

```
io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.5.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.1.3

ERROR ApplicationMaster [Driver]: User class threw exception: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper$class
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper$class
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4873)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:712)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at io.delta.tables.DeltaTable$.forPath(DeltaTable.scala:635)
```

Comment: Could you check what's the version of `jackson-module-scala` in your classpath? Looks like you are using an incompatible version.

Comment: I am using 2.11.1

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Spark 2.4.6 is using 2.6.7.1 ( https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.6/pom.xml#L162 ) It's better to use the same version. `com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper` is no longer in jackson-module-scala 2.11.1.

Comment: Thanks !! tried the same but still the same issue. Getting same error in spark shell also

Comment: Looks like it's still there. You can run print `classOf[com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper].getResource("ScalaObjectMapper.class")` in your codes to see where it comes from. `ScalaObjectMapper` moved to this new package in  jackson-module-scala 2.11.

Comment: checked in spark shell and see the below - scala> print (classOf[com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper].getResource("ScalaObjectMapper.class"))
jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.6.0-77/spark2/jars/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.10.0.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/ScalaObjectMapper.class   .. I will try to use 2.6.7.1

Comment: It was showing this - ClassPAth-jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.6.0-77/spark2/jars/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.10.0.jar!/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/experimental/ScalaObjectMapper.class Working with HDinsight Team

Comment: @NITINGUPTA Any resolution you received from HDInsight team?

Comment: try update scala to 2.12.10

Answer (score 1):

There is conflict between version of jackson-json libraries packaged with HDInsight and used by spark,deltalake

There are 2 options to get around this

1. Packaged jackson json 2.6.7 version dependencies into your application (maven shade plugin or scala assembly)

Or

2. Set below spark configurations, if you are using jupyter notebook

> ```
> {"conf":
>  {"spark.jars.packages": "io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.5.0", 
>     "spark.driver.extraClassPath":
>      "${PATH}/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.7.1.jar;${PATH}/jackson-annotations-2.6.7.jar;
>       ${PATH}/jackson-core-2.6.7.jar;
>       ${PATH}/jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar;
>       ${PATH}/jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.7.jar",
>    "spark.executor.extraClassPath":
>      "${PATH}/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.6.7.1.jar;${PATH}/jackson-annotations-2.6.7.jar;
>       ${PATH}/jackson-core-2.6.7.jar;${PATH}/jackson-databind-2.6.7.1.jar;
>       ${PATH}/jackson-module-paranamer-2.6.7.jar",
>    "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst":true}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @blob, the error is a result of version conflict.

If you're using a maven based project, then you can easily configure your maven shade plugin to rename the Jackson related dependencies of delta so that the conflict is resolved.

```
<plugins>
... 
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>NAME-OF-YOUR-SHADED-JAR-FILE</finalName>
          <filters> <!-- exclude these files from artifacts to avoid SecurityException on signed jars -->
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
          <relocations> <!-- renames the packages so that delta uses these instead of provided jars -->
            <relocation>
              <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>noc.com.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
            <relocation><!-- optional -->
              <pattern>com.google.guava</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>noc.com.google.guava</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Also make sure that your pom.xml has these dependencies in given order:

```
 <!-- jackson related dependencies of delta -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- /jackson related dependency of delta -->

<!-- delta -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
  <artifactId>delta-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- /delta -->
```