# How to use delta lake with Spark 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm using Spark 2.4.4, when I enter pyspark shell, I specify delta lake and jackson packages as below:

```
    pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.6.1,com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.6.7.1 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

**But then got below error:**

> > > > data.write.format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")
> > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > > File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
> > > > line 738, in save
> > > > self.*jwrite.save(path)
> > > > File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
> > > > line 1257, in **call**
> > > > File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63,
> > > > in deco
> > > > return f(*a, **kw)
> > > > File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
> > > > line 328, in get_return_value
> > > > py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o91.save.
> > > > : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper.com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$experimental$ScalaObjectMapper$*setter*$com$fasterxml$jackson$module$scala$experimental$ScalaObjectMapper$$MAP*$eq(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
> > > > at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper$class.$init$(ScalaObjectMapper.scala:331)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.JsonUtils$$anon$1.(JsonUtils.scala:27)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.JsonUtils$.(JsonUtils.scala:27)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.util.JsonUtils$.(JsonUtils.scala)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOperations$Write$$anonfun$1.apply(DeltaOperations.scala:58)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOperations$Write$$anonfun$1.apply(DeltaOperations.scala:58)
> > > > at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaOperations$Write.(DeltaOperations.scala:58)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WriteIntoDelta.scala:66)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta$$anonfun$run$1.apply(WriteIntoDelta.scala:64)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:188)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:64)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:134)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
> > > > at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
> > > > at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> > > > at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> > > > at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> > > > at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> > > > at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> > > > at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> > > > at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> > > > at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> > > > at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> > > > at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> > > > at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: why are you specifying `jackson-module-scala` explicitly?

Comment: just tested with Spark 2.4.6 - works just fine.  Check with what Scala version your Spark is compiled - do the `ls jars/*_2.1*` from spark folder, it should have `_2.11` on all jars.  If not, then you need to use delta compiled for Scala 2.12

Comment: Hi Alex, yes, it do have jackson-module-scala 2.11 in jars folder. But if I don't specify jajckson-module-scala, the error is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liualexiang/images/master/pyspark%20error

Comment: I would say that it could be some dependency conflict in HDP... I would try to create an uberjar of delta with its dependencies, and use it...

Comment: How to specify spark version when build delta uber jar? https://github.com/delta-io/connectors#delta-uber-jar

Comment: as I understand you need to checkout corresponding branch - 0.6 for Spark 2.4.x

Comment: but seems there is only master branch currently: https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/branches/all

Comment: just create a dummy pom.xml that includes dependency on delta + jackson, and build the uberjar

Comment: @AlexOtt any update on this? Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @AlexLiu any updates on issue? did you resolve it?

Comment: If anyone is still facing such error, please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69617788/8215996